# Generating Shared library for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling

Currently I'm able to develop an .dll libraries based on my native C++ code. Recently I got a requirement for same library for Android arm-v7 and also Linux architecture.

How can I generate native libraries for those architectures any cross compiler links would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual Studio supports cross-compilstion for Android, see these instructions for installation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn707598.aspx.

Note that VS may not be ready for the latest NDK release r17, it's OK to use the supported older release letter, e.g. r15.

And here is a short tutorial to get you on board: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn707595.aspx.

And here is the official tutorial for Linux cross-compilation: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the latest version of NDK you can write an `Android.mk` file and then compile your binary using the `ndk-build` script. See the official documentation here: [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk), [ndk-build](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-build). You can also incorporate NDK into your existing toolchain as described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).